# Erro de direitos autorais

Tags: google-play

Estou tentando publicar um aplicativo na Google Play, na primeira vez falou que violava os termos do YouTube, depois mudei e retirei os app do WordPress que usava o YouTube. Não deu mais o erro, mas agora está falando que as imagens violam os direitos autorais.

As imagens ficam hospedadas em um fórum, dentro do Flickr, acredito que talvez isto esteja causando o problema.

O App está em um Iframe, que vai para o site http://paozimdequeijo.com.br/

O Google Play não dá mais informações do que pode estar acontecendo. Preciso que aquele App esteja na loja.

No caso não há mais espaço no servidor para hospedar as imagens no próprio *blog*, então como posso resolver isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, a Google possui sua Content Policy definida neste link:
https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_br/about/developer-content-policy.html

Recomendo que verifique com a responsável pelo site se ela possui os direitos de todas as imagens. Acredito que se ao menos uma destas imagens estiver infringindo direitos autorais, já seja motivo suficiente para a recusa da Google Play.

Comment: Então, eu coloquei outros aplicativos na Google Play, mas só este está dando pau. Acredito que seja o Flickr mesmo. O Google verifica que a imagem está vindo de outro servidor e acusa como violação dos direitos autorais.

Comment: Não tem como vc pegar as imagens e hospedar vc mesmo em algum servidor que não dê o mesmo erro?

Comment: Até teria, porém a dona do aplicativo queria buscar diretamente do Flickr, então não sei como eu poderia fazer para mostrar para o google que aquilo pertence ao dono do aplicativo. Talvez a solução seria eu fazer um algorítmo que pegasse a imagem do flickr por API e armazenasse no meu servidor, para posteriormente utiliza-las e não de este erro de direitos autorais.